Apache Kakfa - Parallelisation within same Consumer
As I am relatively new to Kafka, as I understand we have a hard limit of max 1 consumer per partition in Kafka setup. Also Kafka tries to maintain order within same partition at the expanse of throughput.
In my specific use-case, high throughput is highly important and maintaining order is not required. Kafka also needs to work in ack mode, to prevent any loss of requests in case of failures. Also if any insights if suggested solution with work with AWS MSK it would be great.
Is there a way to consume next set of Kafka messages without acknowledging previous one. Can max-in-flight-requests-per-connection can be leveraged Or is there any other mechanism to continuously consume messages then manually update offset. Please suggest some reference if possible.
Also please note - In have already explored but not possible because of use-case restrictions like requests are highly delay sensitive and individual requests can have delays of around 10 secs because of downstream dependencies.

Increasing number of partitions
Increasing efficiency of request processing in consumer - average case scenario cannot be improved better than 5 sec per request and incoming request traffic is around 50 TPS.
Standalone batching is also not possible messages in queue are delay sensitive and cannot be delayed more than 2 secs.

